How to add one day to the enddate (date format) in API
We currently updating enddate for a user from saviynt application to active directory through API.
So now I have a requirement to add one day to the enddate inside API and pass to active directory.
Below the attribute mapping we are passing:
"accountExpires": "${
if((user.employeeType.equals('Contractor')) & (user?.enddate!=null))
{10000*(user?.enddate.getTime()+11644473600000+18400000)} 
else {'0'}}"

ENDDATE format is : Mar 03, 2022 00:00:00
Now I needs to add one day to this in above mapping.
May I know how can I do this requirement?

You can add  86400000 milliseconds, corresponding to 1 day =  24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds

What's the actual type of enddate in Java?

What is the language used for that 'mapping'? It doesn't seems like Java.

You may add number of milliseconds in a day, i.e. 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 18400000, in the method:
"accountExpires": "${
if((user.employeeType.equals('Contractor')) & (user?.enddate!=null))
{10000 * (user?.enddate.getTime() + 86400000 + 11644473600000 + 18400000)} 
else {'0'}}"

